# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/server/namenode/NameNode

Tags: hadoop

In my shell I do this, but get the result as below.

> > 24king@24king-PC /usr/local/hadoop
> >       $ **sh -x bin/hdfs namenode -format**
>
> ---
>
> ++ which bin/hdfs
>   + bin=/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hdfs
>   ++ dirname /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hdfs
>   + bin=/usr/local/hadoop/bin
>   ++ cd /usr/local/hadoop/bin
>   ++ pwd
>   + bin=/usr/local/hadoop/bin
>   + DEFAULT_LIBEXEC_DIR=/usr/local/hadoop/bin/../libexec
>   + HADOOP_LIBEXEC_DIR=/usr/local/hadoop/bin/../libexec
>   + . /usr/local/hadoop/bin/../libexec/hdfs-config.sh
>   +++ which bin/hdfs
>   ++ bin=/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hdfs
>   +++ dirname /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hdfs
>   ++ bin=/usr/local/hadoop/bin
>   +++ cd /usr/local/hadoop/bin
>   +++ pwd
>   ++ bin=/usr/local/hadoop/bin
>   ++ DEFAULT_LIBEXEC_DIR=/usr/local/hadoop/bin/../libexec
>   ++ HADOOP_LIBEXEC_DIR=/usr/local/hadoop/bin/../libexec
>   ++ '[' -e /usr/local/hadoop/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh ']'
>   ++ . /usr/local/hadoop/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh
>   +++ this=/usr/local/hadoop/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh
>   +++++ dirname -- /usr/local/hadoop/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh
>   ++++ cd -P -- /usr/local/hadoop/bin/../libexec
>   ++++ pwd -P
>   +++ common_bin=/usr/local/hadoop/libexec
>   ++++ basename -- /usr/local/hadoop/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh
>   +++ script=hadoop-config.sh
>   +++ this=/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/hadoop-config.sh
>   +++ '[' -f /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/hadoop-layout.sh ']'
>   +++ HADOOP_COMMON_DIR=share/hadoop/common
>   +++ HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_JARS_DIR=share/hadoop/common/lib
>   +++ HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=lib/native
>   +++ HDFS_DIR=share/hadoop/hdfs
>   +++ HDFS_LIB_JARS_DIR=share/hadoop/hdfs/lib
>   +++ YARN_DIR=share/hadoop/yarn
>   +++ YARN_LIB_JARS_DIR=share/hadoop/yarn/lib
>   +++ MAPRED_DIR=share/hadoop/mapreduce
>   +++ MAPRED_LIB_JARS_DIR=share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib
>   ++++ cd -P -- /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/..
>   ++++ pwd -P
>   +++ HADOOP_DEFAULT_PREFIX=/usr/local/hadoop
>   +++ HADOOP_PREFIX=/usr/local/hadoop
>   +++ export HADOOP_PREFIX
>   +++ '[' 2 -gt 1 ']'
>   +++ '[' --config = namenode ']'
>   +++ '[' -e /usr/local/hadoop/conf/hadoop-env.sh ']'
>   +++ DEFAULT_CONF_DIR=etc/hadoop
>   +++ export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop
>   +++ HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop
>   +++ [[ '' != '' ]]
>   +++ '[' 2 -gt 1 ']'
>   +++ '[' --hosts = namenode ']'
>   +++ '[' --hostnames = namenode ']'
>   +++ [[ '' != '' ]]
>   +++ '[' -f /usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh ']'
>   +++ . /usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh
>   ++++ export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.6.0_45
>   ++++ JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.6.0_45
>   ++++ export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop
>   ++++ HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop
>   ++++ for f in '$HADOOP_HOME/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar'
>   ++++ '[' '' ']'
>   ++++ export 'HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar'
>   ++++ HADOOP_CLASSPATH='/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar'
>   ++++ export 'HADOOP_OPTS= -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true'
>   ++++ HADOOP_OPTS=' -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true'
>   ++++ export 'HADOOP_NAMENODE_OPTS=-Dhadoop.security.logger=INFO,RFAS -Dhdfs.audit.logger=INFO,NullAppender '
>   ++++ HADOOP_NAMENODE_OPTS='-Dhadoop.security.logger=INFO,RFAS -Dhdfs.audit.logger=INFO,NullAppender '
>   ++++ export 'HADOOP_DATANODE_OPTS=-Dhadoop.security.logger=ERROR,RFAS '
>   ++++ HADOOP_DATANODE_OPTS='-Dhadoop.security.logger=ERROR,RFAS '
>   ++++ export 'HADOOP_SECONDARYNAMENODE_OPTS=-Dhadoop.security.logger=INFO,RFAS
>   -Dhdfs.audit.logger=INFO,NullAppender '
>   ++++ HADOOP_SECONDARYNAMENODE_OPTS='-Dhadoop.security.logger=INFO,RFAS -Dhdfs.audit.logger=INFO,NullAppender '
>   ++++ export HADOOP_NFS3_OPTS=
>   ++++ HADOOP_NFS3_OPTS=
>   ++++ export 'HADOOP_PORTMAP_OPTS=-Xmx512m '
>   ++++ HADOOP_PORTMAP_OPTS='-Xmx512m '
>   ++++ export 'HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS=-Xmx512m '
>   ++++ HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS='-Xmx512m '
>   ++++ export HADOOP_SECURE_DN_USER=
>   ++++ HADOOP_SECURE_DN_USER=
>   ++++ export HADOOP_SECURE_DN_LOG_DIR=/
>   ++++ HADOOP_SECURE_DN_LOG_DIR=/
>   ++++ export HADOOP_PID_DIR=
>   ++++ HADOOP_PID_DIR=
>   ++++ export HADOOP_SECURE_DN_PID_DIR=
>   ++++ HADOOP_SECURE_DN_PID_DIR=
>   ++++ export HADOOP_IDENT_STRING=24king
>   ++++ HADOOP_IDENT_STRING=24king
>   ++++ export HADOOP_PREFIX=/usr/local/hadoop
>   ++++ HADOOP_PREFIX=/usr/local/hadoop
>   ++++ export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
>   ++++ HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
>   ++++ /sbin/sysctl -n net.ipv6.bindv6only
>   +++ bindv6only=
>   +++ '[' -n '' ']'
>   +++ export MALLOC_ARENA_MAX=4
>   +++ MALLOC_ARENA_MAX=4
>   +++ [[ -z /usr/local/jdk1.6.0_45 ]]
>   +++ JAVA=/usr/local/jdk1.6.0_45/bin/java
>   +++ JAVA_HEAP_MAX=-Xmx1000m
>   +++ '[' '' '!=' '' ']'
>   +++ CLASSPATH=/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop
>   +++ IFS=
>   +++ '[' /usr/local/hadoop = '' ']'
>   +++ '[' -d /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/webapps ']'
>   +++ '[' -d /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib ']'
>   +++ CLASSPATH='/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/*'
>   +++ CLASSPATH='/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/*'
>   +++ '[' '' = '' ']'
>   +++ HADOOP_LOG_DIR=/usr/local/hadoop/logs
>   +++ '[' '' = '' ']'
>   +++ HADOOP_LOGFILE=hadoop.log
>   +++ '[' '' = '' ']'
>   +++ HADOOP_POLICYFILE=hadoop-policy.xml
>   +++ unset IFS
>   +++ '[' -d /usr/local/hadoop/build/native -o -d /usr/local/hadoop/lib/native ']'
>   +++ '[' -d /usr/local/hadoop/lib/native ']'
>   +++ '[' x '!=' x ']'
>   +++ JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/hadoop/lib/native
>   +++ TOOL_PATH='/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/*'
>   +++ HADOOP_OPTS=' -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.log.dir=/usr/local/hadoop/logs'
>   +++ HADOOP_OPTS=' -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.log.dir=/usr/local/hadoop/logs -Dhadoop.log.file=hadoop.log'
>   +++ HADOOP_OPTS=' -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.log.dir=/usr/local/hadoop/logs -Dhadoop.log.file=hadoop.log -Dhadoop.home.dir=/usr/local/hadoop'
>   +++ HADOOP_OPTS=' -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.log.dir=/usr/local/hadoop/logs -Dhadoop.log.file=hadoop.log -Dhadoop.home.dir=/usr/local/hadoop -Dhadoop.id.str=24king'
>   +++ HADOOP_OPTS=' -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.log.dir=/usr/local/hadoop/logs -Dhadoop.log.file=hadoop.log -Dhadoop.home.dir=/usr/local/hadoop -Dhadoop.id.str=24king -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,console'
>   +++ '[' x/usr/local/hadoop/lib/native '!=' x ']'
>   +++ HADOOP_OPTS=' -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.log.dir=/usr/local/hadoop/logs -Dhadoop.log.file=hadoop.log -Dhadoop.home.dir=/usr/local/hadoop -Dhadoop.id.str=24king -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,console -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/hadoop/lib/native'
>   +++ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=:/usr/local/hadoop/lib/native
>   +++ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=:/usr/local/hadoop/lib/native
>   +++ HADOOP_OPTS=' -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.log.dir=/usr/local/hadoop/logs -Dhadoop.log.file=hadoop.log -Dhadoop.home.dir=/usr/local/hadoop -Dhadoop.id.str=24king -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,console -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/hadoop/lib/native -Dhadoop.policy.file=hadoop-policy.xml'
>   +++ HADOOP_OPTS=' -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.log.dir=/usr/local/hadoop/logs -Dhadoop.log.file=hadoop.log -Dhadoop.home.dir=/usr/local/hadoop -Dhadoop.id.str=24king -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,console -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/hadoop/lib/native -Dhadoop.policy.file=hadoop-policy.xml -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true'
>   +++ '[' '' = '' ']'
>   +++ '[' -d /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs ']'
>   +++ export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
>   +++ HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
>   +++ '[' -d /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/webapps ']'
>   +++ CLASSPATH='/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs'
>   +++ '[' -d /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib ']'
>   +++ CLASSPATH='/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*'
>   +++ CLASSPATH='/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/*'
>   +++ '[' '' = '' ']'
>   +++ '[' -d /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn ']'
>   +++ export HADOOP_YARN_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
>   +++ HADOOP_YARN_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
>   +++ '[' -d /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/webapps ']'
>   +++ '[' -d /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib ']'
>   +++ CLASSPATH='/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*'
>   +++ CLASSPATH='/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/*'
>   +++ '[' '' = '' ']'
>   +++ '[' -d /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce ']'
>   +++ export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
>   +++ HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
>   +++ '[' /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce '!=' /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn ']'
>   +++ '[' -d /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/webapps ']'
>   +++ '[' -d /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib ']'
>   +++ CLASSPATH='/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*'
>   +++ CLASSPATH='/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*'
>   +++ '[' '/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar' '!=' '' ']'
>   +++ '[' '' '!=' '' ']'
>   +++ CLASSPATH='/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar'
>   + '[' 2 = 0 ']'
>   + COMMAND=namenode
>   + shift
>   + case $COMMAND in
>   + '[' namenode == datanode ']'
>   + '[' namenode = namenode ']'
>   + CLASS=org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode
>   + HADOOP_OPTS=' -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.log.dir=/usr/local/hadoop/logs -Dhadoop.log.file=hadoop.log -Dhadoop.home.dir=/usr/local/hadoop -Dhadoop.id.str=24king -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,console -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/hadoop/lib/native -Dhadoop.policy.file=hadoop-policy.xml -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.security.logger=INFO,RFAS -Dhdfs.audit.logger=INFO,NullAppender '
>   + export 'CLASSPATH=/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar'
>   + CLASSPATH='/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar'
>   + HADOOP_OPTS=' -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.log.dir=/usr/local/hadoop/logs -Dhadoop.log.file=hadoop.log -Dhadoop.home.dir=/usr/local/hadoop -Dhadoop.id.str=24king -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,console -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/hadoop/lib/native -Dhadoop.policy.file=hadoop-policy.xml -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.security.logger=INFO,RFAS -Dhdfs.audit.logger=INFO,NullAppender  -Dhadoop.security.logger=INFO,NullAppender'
>   + '[' '' = true ']'
>   + exec /usr/local/jdk1.6.0_45/bin/java 
>   -Dproc_namenode -Xmx1000m 
>   -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true 
>   -Dhadoop.log.dir=/usr/local/hadoop/logs 
>   -Dhadoop.log.file=hadoop.log 
>   -Dhadoop.home.dir=/usr/local/hadoop 
>   -Dhadoop.id.str=24king 
>   -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,console 
>   -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/hadoop/lib/native 
>   -Dhadoop.policy.file=hadoop-policy.xml 
>   -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true 
>   -Dhadoop.security.logger=INFO,RFAS 
>   -Dhdfs.audit.logger=INFO,NullAppender 
>   -Dhadoop.security.logger=INFO,NullAppender **org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode -format java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/server/namenode/NameNode Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247) Could not find the main class:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.**  Program will exit.
>   Exception in thread "main" 24king@24king-PC /usr/local/hadoop $ vim
>   etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh

**Just So, I modify the shell script hdfs add -cp**

Also don't work.

---

> - HADOOP_OPTS=' -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.log.dir=/usr/local/hadoop/logs -Dhadoop.log.file=hadoop.log -Dhadoop.home.dir=/usr/local/hadoop -Dhadoop.id.str=24king -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,console -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/hadoop/lib/native -Dhadoop.policy.file=hadoop-policy.xml -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.security.logger=INFO,RFAS -Dhdfs.audit.logger=INFO,NullAppender '
> - export 'CLASSPATH=/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar'
> - CLASSPATH='/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar'
> - HADOOP_OPTS=' -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.log.dir=/usr/local/hadoop/logs -Dhadoop.log.file=hadoop.log -Dhadoop.home.dir=/usr/local/hadoop -Dhadoop.id.str=24king -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,console -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/hadoop/lib/native -Dhadoop.policy.file=hadoop-policy.xml -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.security.logger=INFO,RFAS -Dhdfs.audit.logger=INFO,NullAppender  -Dhadoop.security.logger=INFO,NullAppender'
> - '[' '' = true ']'
> - exec /usr/local/jdk1.6.0_45/bin/java -Dproc_namenode -Xmx1000m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.log.dir=/usr/local/hadoop/logs -Dhadoop.log.file=hadoop.log -Dhadoop.home.dir=/usr/local/hadoop -Dhadoop.id.str=24king -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,console -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/hadoop/lib/native -Dhadoop.policy.file=hadoop-policy.xml -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.security.logger=INFO,RFAS -Dhdfs.audit.logger=INFO,NullAppender -Dhadoop.security.logger=INFO,NullAppender -cp '/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar'
>     org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode -format
>     java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>     org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/server/namenode/NameNode Caused by:
>     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>     org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
>         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
>         at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247) Could not find the main class:
>     org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.  Program will exit.
>     Exception in thread "main"

Comment: 24king@24king-PC /usr/local/hadoop 
        $ grep "org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode" * -R | grep jar

        Binary file share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-2.4.1-tests.jar matches
        Binary file share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-2.4.1.jar matches
        Binary file share/hadoop/hdfs/sources/hadoop-hdfs-2.4.1-sources.jar matches
        Binary file share/hadoop/hdfs/sources/hadoop-hdfs-2.4.1-test-sources.jar matches
Binary file share/hadoop/httpfs/tomcat/webapps/webhdfs/WEB-INF/lib/hadoop-hdfs-2.4.1.jar matches

Answer (score 0):

Did you add core-site.xml folder with address of namenode properly?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using Cloudera Hadoop. Make sure that `HADOOP_HOME`, `HADOOP_HDFS_HOME` are set to proper directory.
Also check if `hadoop version` command is working. If not, you have to tune up your environment variables in ~/.bashrc file.